# Multiple java language levels in eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an eclipse project where the source output must comply with version 1.3 of the Java language specification

- /src/ (must run on a Java 1.3 JRE)
- /test/ (must run on a Java 1.6 JRE)

The application will run on a java 1.3 JRE (phoneME J2ME Advanced profile, if anyone is curious), while the test code uses JUnit 4, Mockito, etc... and so requires running on a JRE supporting java 1.5 or higher.

I can only seem to configure java language levels on a per-project basis, nothing more granular. At this stage I have set the project language level to 1.6, and use a Makefile to build the final jar with java 1.3 as the target.

Is there a way to have my cake and eat it? Is there a way to set up multiple language levels (and system libraries) within a single project? The only other option I can think of is to split the test code into its own project, which feels like a kludge.

Comment: Nope; not in Eclipse. You could in IntelliJ, I suppose, through modules. But Eclipse's model allows one set of uh... settings per-project.

Comment: IntelliJ and NetBeans have inherent understanding of the concept of separate test sources. Eclipse doesn't, and doesn't seem enthusiastic to ever include it (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=49611). So it seems that "the Eclipse way" to manage your test sources it to place them in a separate project. Which really, really sucks.

Comment: @Dave (& Eli), thanks for the reminder about IntelliJ. Been a few years since I moved away from it, forgotten how useful it was for projects like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible within a single project. But it should be easy to separate the test part out into a second project, that depends on the original.

Comment: Yep, this is actually the advised way to unit test Android projects (for example) as suggested by the Google guys. It actually works quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. Well, if it's good enough for Android then it'll have to be good enough for me.